# Laravel Event - fails with class does not have a method

Tags: php, laravel, queue, listener

Using Laravel 5.5, I have a listener called `JobEventSubscriber` that is using a database queue.  It has a method called `uploadFileToPartner` that is triggered whenever a `JobFilesUploaded` event is fired.

Here is the code of my subscribe method:

```
public function subscribe($events){
    $events->listen(JobSaved::class, JobEventSubscriber::class . '@syncToCrm');
    $events->listen(JobFilesUploaded::class, JobEventSubscriber::class . '@uploadFileToPartner');
}
```

Whenever either of these events fire, the database Listener fails with the following error:

```
ErrorException: call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, 
class 'App\Listeners\JobEventSubscriber' does not have a method 'uploadFileToPartner' 
in /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Events/CallQueuedListener.php:79
```

When I change my `queue_driver` to `sync` it works.  I also went into Tinker and typed:

```
>>> use App\Listeners\JobEventSubscriber
>>> $eventSubscriber = app(JobEventSubscriber::class);
    => App\Listeners\JobEventSubscriber {#879
      +connection: "database",
    }
>>> method_exists($eventSubscriber, 'uploadFileToPartner');
    => true
```

What is wrong here where it cannot find methods that are definitely there.

It may be relevant to mention that I recently updated this app from Larvel 5.4.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upon reading [the docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/queues#running-the-queue-worker) it says that if you change your code you need to restart your queue process.

Specifically it says:

> Remember, queue workers are long-lived processes and store the booted application state in memory. As a result, they will not notice changes in your code base after they have been started. So, during your deployment process, be sure to restart your queue workers.

I changed the name of the methods, and then I didn't restart the queue.  So the queue was receiving events with the new names but it was executing old code.  As a result the method names weren't recognized.